# Dynamically adding field in Django Rest Framework generics.ListAPIView

Tags: geodjango, django-rest-framework

I have a view that can be called with a `longitude` and `latitude` parameters.

When those parameters are set, I want the response to add the distance fields in the serialization.

Here is how I do that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    latitude = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('latitude', None)
    longitude = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('longitude', None)
    if latitude and longitude:
        center = fromstr('POINT(%s %s)'%(latitude,longitude))
        queryset = queryset.distance(center).order_by('distance')
        self.serializer_class.distance = serializers.CharField(source='distance')
        self.serializer_class.Meta.fields += ('distance',)
    return queryset.all()
```

I think I could have done if differently, with two separate `serializer_class`.

I am wondering if it would have been better, what do you think?

Comment: whit these lines
`self.serializer_class.distance = serializers.CharField(source='distance')
self.serializer_class.Meta.fields += ('distance',)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess `distance` is `None` where `longitude` and `latitude` aren't given?

I'd be inclined to define the distance field on the serializer itself, rather than adding it dynamically on the view.

For the case where distance is `None` — if I didn't want it in the response — I would override `to_native` on the serializer to remove it. E.g:

```
def to_native(self, obj):
    ret = super(MySerializer, self).to_native(obj)
    if ret['distance'] is None:         
        del ret['distance']
    return ret
```

The end result is the same but this approach is more *cohesive*. I hope that helps.